# How to do optional parameters in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
(Dc.DET_Cases.Where(c => c.ProductID == pl.ProductID 
                    && oldTOR == false ? c.OldTOR == oldTOR : 
                    && (productLineName.ToInt() == 0 || productLineName.ToInt() == c.ProductLineID)
                    && (productCategory.ToInt() == 0 || productCategory.ToInt() == c.ProductCategoryID)
                    && (issueType.ToInt() == 0 || issueType.ToInt() == c.IssueTypeID)
                    && (issue.ToInt() == 0 || issue.ToInt() == c.IssueID)
                    )
                    .FirstOrDefault() != null)
```

This is the line I'm trying to do.

```
oldTOR == false ? c.OldTOR == oldTOR :
```

inside a `where` LINQ statement. If the value is false then compare the value. If not, then ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just set the other option to be `true`.

Ie: `!oldTOR ? c.OldTOR == oldTOR : true`

This means that if `oldTor` is false, then we want to compare OldTor's, otherwise, keep evaluating the rest of the expression.

As an aside, I would split each part of your massive `.Where()` boolean comparison into individual `.Where()` statements. This will improve readability and comprehension of your Linq.

```
    Dc.DET_Cases
        .Where(c => c.ProductID == pl.ProductID)
        .Where(c => !oldTOR ? c.OldTOR == oldTOR :  true)
        .Where(c => productLineName.ToInt() == 0 || productLineName.ToInt() == c.ProductLineID)
        .Where(c => productCategory.ToInt() == 0 || productCategory.ToInt() == c.ProductCategoryID)
        .Where(c => issueType.ToInt() == 0 || issueType.ToInt() == c.IssueTypeID)
        .Where(c => issue.ToInt() == 0 || issue.ToInt() == c.IssueID)
        .FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

This makes it clear that if `oldTor` is `false` then you want to compare, otherwise, pass that statement (`true`).

Comment: The easiest is (oldTor || c.OldTOR == oldTOR) - no need for ? at all due short-circuting of ||.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

And then create a query as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is by evaluation paths:

```
oldTOR && (c.OldTor == oldTOR)
```

Why is this the fastest? Answer: if `oldTOR` is false then the whole ***and*** statement is false, and there is no need to compare the rest of the statement.

Comment: The OP states that if the value is _false_ then do the comparison. That is use || not &&.